# Sinch audio error on callee side

Tags: android, calling-convention, sinch

```
@Override
public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Call established");

    mCallState.setText(call.getState().toString());
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
    getSinchServiceInterface().getAudioController().enableSpeaker();
}
```

This is the code sample of enabling audio when the connection established
on the caller side it is working well we can heard the loud voice of callee  but on the other hand callee is unable to heard the voice on loud speaker although voice is audible but only on microphone not on loud speaker